# grepping column with (and | or) operators

Tags: grep

I have data that looks like the following:

```
bark    art|evt|evt|nat
barnburner  evt|hum
bash    evt|evt
battle  act|act|act|evt|evt
bay anm|art|art|art|evt|nat|plt
beat    act|act|atr|com|evt|evt|evt|hum|loc|tme
beating act|act|evt|evt
bread   act|act|evt|evt|hum|nat
```

I want to be able to extract from it all lines that have any string in the first column, but a specific pattern of information in the second column.
More specifically, I want to extract those lines that has **evt** in the second column and *at least* another value that I specify.

For instance, I want to extract all lines that have **evt** and *at least* **hum** or **nat** (or both **hum** and **nat** and **evt** simutaneously).
Thus, my desired result would be:

```
bark    art|**evt**|**evt**|**nat**    
barnburner  **evt**|**hum**
bay anm|art|art|art|**evt**|**nat**|plt
beat    act|act|atr|com|**evt**|**evt**|**evt**|**hum**|loc|tme
bread   act|act|**evt**|**evt**|**hum**|**na**t
```

I have been trying to do this with a `grep`with no success.

The grep that I have been trying is:

```
$ grep 'evt\|(hum|nat)' file
```

Can anyone point me in a direction to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using complex `grep` commands, you could consider using `awk`, which handles columns and conditions quite easily. `awk -v FS="|" '$1=="evt" && ($2=="evt" || $2=="act")' file`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep:

- default:  **BRE** (Basic Regex) , you have to escape some special chars to **give** them special meaning. like `|, ( ...`
- -E option: **ERE** (Extened Regex), you escape some special chars to **take** special meaning **away**. like `|, (, {...`

So you used default option of grep, which is **BRE**, the `evt\|(hum|nat)` matches 
`"evt" or literal "(hum|hat)"`   with **BRE**, what you are looking for might be: `evt|\(hum\|nat\)` here `\( and \|` have special meaning.

Or use `-E` BRE, then you can `grep 'evt\|(hum|hat)` , the `\|` took the special meaning away, made it match literal `"|"`

Answer (score 1):

You are so close, just use Extended regex paramter `E`.

```
$ grep -E 'evt\|(hum|nat)' file
bark    art|evt|evt|nat
barnburner  evt|hum
bay anm|art|art|art|evt|nat|plt
beat    act|act|atr|com|evt|evt|evt|hum|loc|tme
bread   act|act|evt|evt|hum|nat
```